# twitter bootstrap - container left shifted and alerts not expanding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**to all moderates reading this message I had asked it in another thread but was told to post it as a stand alone question. Not my intention to cluter the forum**

My twitter bootstrap container is shifted to the left for some reason. Is there any way to make it take up the whole screen despite resolution? When I use .container-fluid, it seems to shrink the overall container (even when I add .row-fluid to all my rows).

My alerts are not increasing in width. That is to say that I would like the alert (background color and all) to be the width of the container. In the link below I would like "If this is your ad login to edit" to span the whole container. However when I try .span12 it just shifts the alert. Also width:100%; does nothing to help. Also when I press login and an a login error occurs the error is shown at the far left instead of right on top of the login form.

** concerning items 2 and 3 refer to this link https://twitter.com/HassanNSaid/status/355797180063301632/photo/1 **
Requested code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row well">
               <?php
                loginFunc();
                miniLogo();
                searchFunc();
                otherOptions();
               ?>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <center>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['error_with_new_title'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-error">'.$_GET['error_with_new_title'].'</span>';
                        }elseif(isset($_GET['success_with_new_title'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-success">'.$_GET['success_with_new_title'].'</span>';
                        }elseif(isset($_GET['error_with_new_vitals'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-error">'.$_GET['error_with_new_vitals'].'</span>';
                        }elseif(isset($_GET['success_with_new_vitals'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-success">'.$_GET['success_with_new_vitals'].'</span>';
                        }elseif(isset($_GET['error_with_new_description'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-error">'.$_GET['error_with_new_description'].'</span>';
                        }elseif(isset($_GET['success_with_new_description'])){
                            echo'<span class="alert-success">'.$_GET['success_with_new_description'].'</span>';
                        }else{
                            echo'<span class="alert">If this is your ad please log in to edit it!</span>';
                        }
                    ?>
               </center>
           </div>
           <div class="row page-header text-center">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                        $i = $_SESSION['id'];
                        printAdTitle($i);
                    }else{
                        $i = 0;
                        printAdTitle($i);
                    }
                ?>
           </div>
           <div class="imagesAndVitals">
            <div class="row span9">
               <center>
                    <? printAdImages($_GET['id']); ?>
               </center>
           </div>
           <div class="row tabbable span6" style="height:374px;">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#adVitalsPane" data-toggle="tab"> Ad Vitals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactUserPane" data-toggle="tab">Contact Seller</a></li>
                </ul>
               <div class="contactVitalsDiv">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="adVitalsPane">
                        <?php 
                             if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                                $i = $_SESSION['id'];
                                printAdVitals($i);
                             }else{
                                $i = 0;
                                printAdVitals($i);
                             } 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="contactUserPane">
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                                $i = $_SESSION['id'];
                                printAdContactForm($i);
                            }else{
                                $i = 0;
                                printAdContactForm($i);
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratingForm">
                    <?php 
                        $adId = $_GET['id'];
                        printRatingForm($adId);
                    ?>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>   
           </div>
            <div class="row text-center descriptionDiv">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                        $i = $_SESSION['id'];
                        printAdDescription($i);
                    }else{
                        $i = 0;
                        printAdDescription($i);
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#similarItmesPane" data-toggle="tab">Similar Items</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#otherUserItemsPane" data-toggle="tab">User's Other Items</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="similarItmesPane">
                            <? printSimilarItems(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="otherUserItemsPane">
                            <? printOtherItems(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you show us some code? Or even a jsFiddle. Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing what you did...

Comment: I'm using the default twitter bootstrap non mininfied verision

Comment: could you make that the rendered HTML, not your PHP...

Comment: view below for the rendered html

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Scoopclassifieds.com - Test4 posted under Electronics/Laptop</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/editFormValidation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customStyles.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body onLoad="addOption_list();">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row well">

                <form class="form-inline pull-right" action="controllers/login.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="span2" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" class="span2" />
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn" />
                </form>
            <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w300-h200-q60/scoopclassifieds/images/scoop3.png" alt="miniLogo" />
           <form action="search.php" method="get" name="search_form" id="search_form" class="form-search pagination-centered">
                <input type="text" name="searchFor" id="searchFor" class="searchInput span10" />
                <input type="text" name="min" id="min" placeholder="Min Price" class="span2 text-center" />
                <input type="text" name="max" id="max" placeholder="Max Price" class="span2 text-center" />
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="span2 text-center" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
            </form>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="add.php" class="otherAdd">Add</a></li>
                <li><a href="browse.php" class="otherBrowse">Browse</a></li>
            </ul>
                   </div>
           <div class="row">
               <center>
                    <span class="alert">If this is your ad please log in to edit it!</span>               </center>
           </div>
           <div class="row page-header text-center">
                <div id="item_title"><br/><span style="font-size:35px; font-weight:bold;">Test4</span></div>           </div>
           <div class="imagesAndVitals">
            <div class="row span9">
               <center>

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel well span8">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w500-h374-q60//classy/images/6/test4/61Ec8SFYZoL._SS500_.jpg" id="0" alt="image0" class="item active" />

                                <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w500-h374-q60//classy/images/6/test4/0176440763.jpg" id="1" alt="image1" class="item" />
                            </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
                       </center>
           </div>
           <div class="row tabbable span6" style="height:374px;">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#adVitalsPane" data-toggle="tab"> Ad Vitals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactUserPane" data-toggle="tab">Contact Seller</a></li>
                </ul>
               <div class="contactVitalsDiv">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="adVitalsPane">

                <span class="well span5" style="font-size:30px; color:white; text-align:center; background:#BC4F0F;">$124</span><br/>
                <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Location:</span><span style="font-size:14px;">Ottawa</span><br/>
                <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Category:</span><span style="font-size:14px;">Electronics</span><br/>
                <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Sub-Category:</span><span style="font-size:14px;">Laptop</span>
                                </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="contactUserPane">

            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Email:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="viewInput" /><br/>
                <label>Message:</label><br/>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="input"></textarea><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="contactUser" id="contactUser" value="Contact User" class="button" />
            </form>
                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratingForm">

            <div class="modal hide fade" id="userFeedback" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Give us some feedback about this user</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                       <h5>The Good</h5>
                       <input type="radio" name="feedBack" value="Good1">Good1<br/>
                       <input type="radio" name="feedBack" value="Good2">Good2<br/>
                       <input type="radio" name="feedBack" value="Good3">Good3<br/><br/>
                       <input type="submit" name="giveFeedBack" id="giveFeedBack" class="btn btn-success" value="Give Feedback" />
                       </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#userFeedback" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Give feedback</a>
                        </div>
               </div>
            </div>   
           </div>
            <div class="row text-center descriptionDiv">
                <span class="page-header descriptionHeader">Description:</span><br/><div id="item_description">&quot;But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who lov</div>            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#similarItmesPane" data-toggle="tab">Similar Items</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#otherUserItemsPane" data-toggle="tab">User's Other Items</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="similarItmesPane">
                            <h4>Ads with similar category of: Electronics</h4><ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="span4"><a href="view.php?id=2&amp;title=test3" class="thumbnail" style="height:235px; width:300px;" id="secondary-info" rel="popover" data-content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the..." data-original-title="Price: $1234<br/>Location: Ottawa<br/>Electronics/Television">
                                <center>Test3</center>
                                <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w300-h200-q60/" alt="Test3MainImage" />
                            </a></li>

                            <li class="span4"><a href="view.php?id=24&amp;title=test21" class="thumbnail" style="height:235px; width:300px;" id="secondary-info" rel="popover" data-content="There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or..." data-original-title="Price: $1245<br/>Location: Ottawa<br/>Electronics/Laptop">
                                <center>Test21</center>
                                <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w300-h200-q60/" alt="Test21MainImage" />
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="otherUserItemsPane">
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span4"><a href="view.php?id=2&amp;title=test3" class="thumbnail" style="height:235px; width:300px;" id="secondary-info" rel="popover" data-content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the..." data-original-title=" Price: $1234<br/> Location: Ottawa<br/>Electronics/Television">
                        <center>Test3</center>
                        <img src="/scoopclassifieds/slir/w300-h200-q60/" alt="Test3MainImage" />
                    </a></li>
                </ul>                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 

            </div>
            <div class="footer">

            <a href="index.php" class="footerHome">Home</a> | <a href="contact.php" class="footerContact">Contact Us</a><br/>
            Scoop Classifieds &copy;
        2013            </div>
        </div> -->
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            function(){
                $('#myCarousel').carousel();
                $('[rel="popover"]').popover();
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```